# Visual Composer; custom elements won't load textarea_html/'content'

Tags: wordpress

Currently using WordPress 4.4.2, I'm in the process of developing some custom Visual Composer elements.

It seems (however), that whenever I want to use a textarea_html param (So the end-user can use the wysiwyg editor) I cannot seem to grab it's contents when rendering the template.

Contents of 'titled_content_box.php'

```
// called during vc_before_init
function integrate_titled_content_box(){
    register_titled_content_box();
    add_shortcode( 'titled_content_box', 'titled_content_box_func');
}

//Mapping of titled-contentbox
function register_titled_content_box(){
    vc_map( array(
        "name"              =>  __( "Content box with Title", "mytheme"),
        "base"              =>  "titled_content_box",
        "class"             =>  "",
        "category"          =>  "Content",
        "params"            =>  array(
            array(
                "type"          =>  "textfield",
                "holder"        =>  "div",
                "class"         =>  "",
                "heading"       =>  __( "Title", "mytheme"),
                "param_name"    =>  "title",
                "value"         =>  __("Box title", "mytheme"),
                "description"   =>  __("The title covering the content box", "mytheme")
            ),
            array(
                "type"          =>  "textarea_html",
                "holder"        =>  "div",
                "class"         =>  "",
                "heading"       =>  __( "Description", "mytheme"),
                "param_name"    =>  "content",
                "value"         =>  '<p>Placeholder</p>',
                "description"   =>  __("The content", "mytheme")
            )
        )
    ));
}

// Setting values where necessary and fetching the template
function titled_content_box_func( $atts ){
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'title'      =>  'title',
        'content'    =>  'content'
    ), $atts) );

    return include_vc_template('titled_content_box.php', $atts);
}

add_action ( 'vc_before_init', 'integrate_titled_content_box');
```

contents of the template used at the return statement:

```
<div class="titled-content-box">
    <div class="title"><span><?php echo $atts['title']; ?></span></div>    
    <div class="content">
        <?php echo $atts['content']; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know why my content-field is not loaded? The element itself is loaded, I can use it in VC... even the Title will be loaded and if I replace the field with a textbox, all still works fine and dandy...
My end-user wants to format his content and is not able to use html formatting.

The only function not included is the 'include_vc_template' function, but all that does is pretty much fetching a string-defined php-file on a predetermined location and injects the $atts array. In all other elements I've made that works perfectly fine.
However, for completeness i'll include it here;

```
function include_vc_template($template, $atts){
    if(is_file(__DIR__.'/vc_templates/'.$template)){
        ob_start();
        include __DIR__.'/vc_templates/'.$template;
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    return false;
}
```

As this is a project i'm working on in my spare-time I can't help but to feel annoyed by a functionality not working as-documented... Most searches I've done simply referred my back to wpbakery's knowledge base page for vc_map()... Any pointers at all would be great!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update you template callback function to:

```
function titled_content_box_func( $atts, $content ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'title'      =>  'title',
    ), $atts) );
    $atts['content'] = $content;

    return include_vc_template('titled_content_box.php', $atts);
}
```

**Update: 07-11-2016:**

I would recommend using also `vc_map_get_attributes` function, which also combines all default values with your provided values.

As you can see in previous PHP function we used `title` attribute with default value `title` which is not compatible with the default value from `vc_map` (`__("Box title", "mytheme")`) and actually this is an error.

To avoid that errors please use `vc_map_get_attributes` function for `$atts` variable.

```
function titled_content_box_func( $atts, $content, $tag ) {
    $atts = vc_map_get_attributes($tag, $atts);
    $atts['content'] = $content;

    return include_vc_template('titled_content_box.php', $atts);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, such a small error to forget adding in the $content param -.- I feel ashamed.

Comment: Yes actually it is native in wordpress that content attributes goes to $content variable in callback

Answer (score 2):

The content is outputted but not a 100% correct, because it also mixes up the HMTL and creates extra paragraphs.

correct code is:

```
    function titled_content_box_func( $atts, $content = null, $tag ) {
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'title'      =>  'title',
), $atts) );
    $content = wpb_js_remove_wpautop($content, true); // fix unclosed/unwanted paragraph tags in $content

return include_vc_template('titled_content_box.php', $atts);
```

}